# Views Rest Export and sending page numbers in it's response

Tags: views, 8, paging

I have a paginated views using "rest export" and I'm using it to show that data on mobile app, everything works fine, but I want to know how many pages exist on that endpoint to show page numbers in my app.

I know I can alter the view programmatically, but I'm asking if there is a simple solution to achieve this.

This is the view settings page.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of now there is no way to display total page count in views rest export. But you can get **total pages, current page, items per page and total number of items** using new custom style in your custom module which extends existing `Serializer` class as shown below:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_module\Plugin\views\style;

use Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\style\Serializer;

/**
 * The style plugin for serialized output formats.
 *
 * @ingroup views_style_plugins
 *
 * @ViewsStyle(
 *   id = "custom_serializer",
 *   title = @Translation("Custom serializer"),
 *   help = @Translation("Serializes views row data and pager using the Serializer component."),
 *   display_types = {"data"}
 * )
 */
class CustomSerializer extends Serializer {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render() {
    $rows = [];
    // If the Data Entity row plugin is used, this will be an array of entities
    // which will pass through Serializer to one of the registered Normalizers,
    // which will transform it to arrays/scalars. If the Data field row plugin
    // is used, $rows will not contain objects and will pass directly to the
    // Encoder.
    foreach ($this->view->result as $row_index => $row) {
      $this->view->row_index = $row_index;
      $rows[] = $this->view->rowPlugin->render($row);
    }
    unset($this->view->row_index);

    // Get the content type configured in the display or fallback to the
    // default.
    if ((empty($this->view->live_preview))) {
      $content_type = $this->displayHandler->getContentType();
    }
    else {
      $content_type = !empty($this->options['formats']) ? reset($this->options['formats']) : 'json';
    }

    $pager = $this->view->pager;
    $class = get_class($pager);
    $current_page = $pager->getCurrentPage();
    $items_per_page = $pager->getItemsPerPage();
    $total_items = $pager->getTotalItems();
    $total_pages = 0;
    if(!in_array($class, ['Drupal\views\Plugin\views\pager\None', 'Drupal\views\Plugin\views\pager\Some'])){
      $total_pages = $pager->getPagerTotal();
    }

    $result = [
      'rows' => $rows,
      'pager' => [
        'current_page' => $current_page,
        'total_items' => $total_items,
        'total_pages' => $total_pages,
        'items_per_page' => $items_per_page,
      ],
    ];
    return $this->serializer->serialize($result, $content_type, ['views_style_plugin' => $this]);
  }

}
```

After adding above file clear drupal cache and edit the view. There you need to change the format from `Serializer` to `Custom serializer`.

In this style there is a little difference in the output. All rows are children of `rows` and pager information is part of `pager`. Sample output is as shown below:

```
{
   "rows":[
      {
         "title":"Test"
      },
      {
         "title":"Test"
      },
      {
         "title":"Title 5"
      },
      {
         "title":"Title 4"
      },
      {
         "title":"Title 3"
      }
   ],
   "pager":{
      "current_page":0,
      "total_items":6,
      "total_pages":2,
      "items_per_page":5
   }
}
```

Comment: For newbies like me, this needs to be at `modules/custom/yourmodule/src/Plugin/views/style/SerializerName.php`

Comment: @vishal-patil your answer inspired me to write the Pager Serializer module.

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist I am glad it helped you create a module. If it is released you can add a link in comments to help others.

Comment: Welldone @Vishal, I am unable to change to the new Serializer though, when I checked logged messages, I found this: Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginException: Plugin (module_name_serializer) instance class "Drupal\module_name\Plugin\views\style\MySerializer" does not exist. in Drupal\Component\Plugin\Factory\DefaultFactory::getPluginClass() (line 97 of ~/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Factory/DefaultFactory.php).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Never mind @Vishal. I figured it was because I did not add the namespace to my class definition like this:

namespace Drupal\module_name\Plugin\views\style;